# Como agregar la extensión php_printer.dll en xampp/lampp en ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

Debo aclarar que he hecho casi de todo:

```
extension=/opt/lampp/php_printer.dll.
```

Dando permiso a la carpeta claro está y agregando el archivo.

Descargue la dll para la version 5.6 de mi php.

En windows lo probé y funciona de maravilla.

Otra cosa es que no existe ese archivo en `.so`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la [documentació](http://php.net/manual/fa/intro.printer.php)n, **esa extensión sólo puede usarse en windows**, al igual que [otras](http://php.net/manual/fa/refs.utilspec.windows.php) que están pensadas específicamente para funcionar en esa plataforma y no son portables.

También comentarte que las dlls de windows son para windows, no para Linux (salvo que las uses con wine ).

No bostante para enviar archivos a la impresora en Ubuntu y en el resto de sistemas operativos GNU/Linux suele ser mucho más sencillo. En mi caso particular genero primero el archivo pdf, lo guardo en disco y luego lo envío a la impresora directamente:

```
<?
exec("lp docuemnto.pdf");
?>
```

Para más información sobre el comando lp, puedes usar la [página del manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/lp.1.html) ;-)

Comment: Podrías editar tu respuesta y agregar un referencia a la documentación que mencionas. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si lo puse muy escueto, ahora creo que ya está más completo. Gracias por la sugerencia.